# How to use a method with an out parameter in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a method which looks the following way:

```
bool GetIdByName(string name, out ID id)
```

I would like to use it inside a lambda expression, to get several 'ids' by a number of 'names':

```
var ids = names.Select(name => idService.GetIdByName(name, out id));
```

In this case I will find all the bool values inside my 'ids' variable, which is not what I want. Is it also possible to get the out parameter 'id' of each call into it?

Comment: Why are you using an `out` parameter for `id`? Why not simply return the `id` itself? Are there cases when no id exists?

Comment: The existing method which gives back the id was not written by me and I don't want to touch it. Yes there are cases where no id exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a delegate with body for this:

```
IEnumerable<ID> ids = names.Select
(
    name =>
    {
        ID id;
        GetName(name, out id);

        return id;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would factor the call to `GetIdByName` into a method, so that it becomes more composable.

```
var ids = names.Select(GetId);

private static ID GetId(string name)
{
    ID id;
    idService.GetIdByName(name, out id);
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are looking for something like that?

```
var ids = names
  .Select(name => {
    ID id = null; 

    if (!idService.GetIdByName(name, out id))
      id = null; // name doesn't corresponds to any ID

    return id;
  })
  .Where(id => id != null);
```

In case `ID` is a *struct* (and so not *nullable*):

```
  var ids = names
    .Select(name => {
      ID id = null; 
      Boolean found = idService.GetIdByName(name, out id);

      return new {
        Found = found,
        ID = id
      };
    })
    .Where(data => data.Found)
    .Select(data => data.id);
```